# Loop to create and save histograms resulting in error

Tags: r, loops, histogram, data-analysis

I'm trying to create a block of code that will run through each file in a folder (C:/stockHistoryYear/), get the stock return values, create a histogram, and save the histogram for each file
However, the code I am using returns with error

> Error in file(file, "rt") : cannot open the connection

I am new to R and most of my info is from random Youtube videos and this website. I would love any assistance, and additional knowledge you may have

My current code:

```
for (i in 1:length(files)) {
 data <- read.csv(files[i])
 prices <- data[, "Adj.Close"]
 n <- NROW (prices)
 ret <- ((prices[2:n]-prices[1:(n-1)])/prices[1:(n-1)])
 names(ret) <- data[2:n, "Date"]
 picname <- c(toString(files[i]),'.png')
 toString(picname)
 png(picname)
 hist(ret, col = "blue", lwd = 2, ylab = "Frequency", xlab = "Stock Return", 
 main = i)
 dev.off() 
}
```

Performing traceback() resulted in:

```
3: file(file, "rt")
2: read.table(file = file, header = header, sep = sep, quote = quote, 
       dec = dec, fill = fill, comment.char = comment.char, ...)
1: read.csv(files[i])
```

Comment: The error means that R cannot open a file at the specified location. Most likely the path to the file in `files` is incorrect. It would help to see how you are creating the `files` variable and some of its content. Unrelated: your use of `toString` to create an output name will result in a file name with a comma and a space in it. I'd use `paste0` instead.

Comment: When you created `files`, did you use `list.files(...)` without `full.names=TRUE`? If you included a `path=` (to a directory other than `.`) but omitted `full.names=TRUE`, then all of the file names will be confusingly not right.

Comment: thank you all! I've been able to make it work